# Reactjs - jquery not defined in npm installed lib - jquery.reel

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to install the module jquery.reel into my react project.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import reel from 'jquery.reel';
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.reel

When I import it I get this error..I am using the create-app and I think this is an error with the eslite rules?

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:3901:3
  3898 |       commonjs = !amd && typeof module == 'object' && typeof module.exports == 'object' && (module.exports = factory),
  3899 |       plain = !amd && !commonjs && factory();
  3900 | })(function () {
> 3901 |   return jQuery.reel || function ($, window, document, undefined) {
```

Comment: `jQuery is not defined` because you imported it as `$`.  However: just try to use `reel`, not `jQuery.reel`.
When using modern JavaScript you are not relying on global objects that are enhanced by jQuery plugins anymore.

Comment: I did try and import also {$, jQuery} --- but the npm package itself is jquery.reel when you install it

Comment: Using `import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery'` will not work. But this is not your problem. You need to share your code if you want help

Comment: the code borks -- as soon as I try and import the reel module -- it claims there is an error with the module itself

Comment: Uhm... ok. The source code is pretty old (6 years) https://github.com/pisi/Reel/blob/master/jquery.reel.js and it seems it's not usable by import statement. No way webpack can understand it (no commonjs or AMD).

If you really need it try to import jQuery and this plugin globally from your HTML file.

Comment: its as soon as I try and import the module - under the jquery it just borks - I don't think its an issue with the version of jquery -- you able to check this out on a clean build?

Comment: --- I tried to add it as a custom js file - but it still had issues - how do I add it as a plugin globally?